# What we could do is injoy every moment instead of being sad or miserable about life?

Tags: stockquotes

Well the way I see it is that life it's self is tough so you have to show them who's more equal not just by your looks or how much money you make. What counts is that your still alive your still going strong baby keep that up and never look back

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's a lovely sentiment, but has nothing to do with a programming problem

Comment: Why is that? It's means alot from where I come from and having to let and say this means more to me would be appreciated if you don't .